pvlib.clearsky.detect_clearsky returns 'ValueError: index can't contain negative values'
I am using pvlib.clearsky.detect_clearsky to detect if it's clear sky, I am sure the inputs are series data with time, but it  returns 'ValueError: index can't contain negative values'.
Here's my code:
d_GHI = pd.read_excel(ghi_f)['GHI']
d_cr = pd.read_excel(clr_f)['GHI']
d_time_utc = pd.read_excel(ghi_f)['time']

d_GHI.index = d_time_utc
d_cr.index = d_time_utc

series_ghi = pd.Series(d_GHI)
series_cr = pd.Series(d_cr)




clearsky = pvlib.clearsky.detect_clearsky(d_GHI,d_cr)

I tried to change the input arguments as array and assigned times seperately, but still doesn't work

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error as well as the sample data.
